# How should I do to Sort items in object?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)
>   [javascript sort object of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686365/javascript-sort-object-of-objects)

I have an object of objects. Each object have a key:

```
{
    name: {key: value,
           key1:BBB},
    name2: {key: value,
            key1:AAA},
    name3: {key: value,
            key1:CCC}
}
```

I will later select a subset of the keys (name2 and name3 for example): after that I want to sort the remaining items based on the value of key1. How should I go about doin this?

Comment: You cannot sort properties of objects, they are unsorted. You can only sort arrays. Sorting an array of objects is already covered here...

Comment: So what should I do, load the requierd data into an array an then sort it?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren if your object contains only a bunch of objects that are the same structure/schema then you could loop through the main object and move the child objects into an array and sort the array.